# Sending Activity still visible after app is killed

Tags: android, android-intent

I have an issue that my sending `Activity` is still visible after I kill `app`. How to close all `Activity`'s when the app is killed?

DETAILED DESCRIPTION

I have a sending `Intent` in `onDownloadStart` method that displays the user a list of possible apps to "send an image", here you go:

```
Intent sendIntent = new Intent();
sendIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION);
sendIntent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
File filePath = new File(String.valueOf(context.getFilesDir()));
File newFile = new File(filePath, fileName);
sendIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, FileProvider.getUriForFile(context, context.getApplicationContext().getPackageName() + ".FileProvider", newFile));
sendIntent.setType(intentType);
context.startActivity(sendIntent);
```

This code **IS** working as I want with the **ONE** exception. The `Activity` with choosing the app to send the image is still visible when I kill the app. That's all - no errors in the console.

Comment: Add some code and logs if possible. Your question is too broad and hard to understand!

Comment: Show detail description and some code for it .

Comment: everything is working, no errors etc, logs say nothing Just a simple issue and you are downvoting the question :(

Comment: @Xenolion here go, I added some code

Comment: @DivySoni I can't, this is needed. My code needs to be in external class.

Comment: read this, https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK ,It generates new activity independent to previous. that's why when you finish your app than it will not be finished.

Comment: @DivySoni yeah I know, why to prevent that then?

Comment: @DivySoni They are not finished tbh. I said: when my sending Intent (exporting image) is started but I didn't choose the app to start Intent and meanwhile I kill my main app this dialog for choosing app to export is still visible

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/154666/discussion-between-divy-soni-and-soommy12).

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is here:

```
sendIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION);
```

You start the `Activity` to choose an app to send in a new task. When you remove your task from the list of recent tasks (that's what "swiping your app from the recents list" does), the other task you started is still live.

Just remove `Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK` from the `setFlags()` call and the chooser should end up running in your app's task, and therefore go away when you swipe your app's task from the list of recents.

Also, your use of the word `Intent` is confusing. An `Intent` is never visible. It is just a small bit of data used to request that Android launch a certain component. You mean `Activity`, not `Intent`.

Comment: As I said in the another comment, I can't remove this flag because this `Activity` is called from outside the main `Activity` and I will get `android.util.AndroidRuntimeException`

Comment: I'm trying to help you and you downvote my answer? That's not very nice.

Comment: Yes, because you didn't read the content before. That was discussed in the comments earlier, your answer was not helpful. (the guy who told me to do the same thing you told me to do deleted the comment)

Comment: Please post the code that calls this code and explain where it is that you need FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK